# Delta function with both limits of the integral set to zero

Tags: distribution-theory

What is the expression

$$\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0}\int_0^t f(s)\,\delta(t-s)\,ds,$$

where $f(s)$ is some "nice" function?

Comment: What is delta? What is a nice function?

Comment: It would be easier to compute this if the upper limit was $t+\varepsilon$ for some small $\varepsilon>0,$ because then the $t$ would be squarely inside the interval of integration, and the usual delta function property would come to the fore.

Comment: @Klangen: $\delta$ is almost certainly the Dirac Delta function.

Comment: Do you know what $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)$ is?

Comment: If $\varepsilon>0,$ then $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^{t+\varepsilon}f(s)\,\delta(t-s)\,ds=\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t),$$ whatever that is.

Comment: Sorry, the limits were wrong! It should be t going to zero!

Comment: With $\delta$ I mean Dirac Delta function, with "nice" I mean continuous and differentiable

Comment: That expression is not well-defined. If forced at gunpoint to give it a value, I would choose $\frac12 f(0)$, because surely the $\delta$-function is symmetric about $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\delta(s)$ is an even function, we can replace $\delta(t-s)$ with $\delta(s-t)$, where we can see that the function has been moved to the right with the amount of $t$. Then we have: $$ \lim_{t \to 0}\int_0^t f(s)\delta(s-t) ds$$ The trick is to know that $\int_0^t f(s)\delta(s-t)ds$ gives back the value of $f(s)$ at $t = s$. ([Sampling Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation)) You can think about the Dirac-Delta as if it had the value $1$ at $0$, and the value $0$ anywhere else. Than it is understandable that $f(s)\delta(s-t)$ has the value $f(t)$ at $t$ and $0$ anywhere else. If you integrate it you get the only available non-zero value. (Note that this argument is obviously not strict, but intuitive.) So the full solution: $$\lim_{t \to 0}\int_0^t f(s)\delta(s-t)ds = \lim_{t \to 0} f(t) = f(0)$$
But in order to use this the integration should take place between $0$ and $t+\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$ as already mentioned in the comments. This way the integral is simply undefined.